# Pandas DataFrame formatting

Tags: python, pandas, string-formatting

I have a pandas DataFrame with mixed values in it.  I am working in Ipython notebook while developing it.   When displaying the dataframe I would  like it to display to facilitate easier reading.   At the moment I am using python string formatting to display all floats to 4 decimals and to add thousand separators.

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.4f}'.format
```

Ideally I would like to E.g. Display Values over 10000 without decimals,   fractions with 4 significant digits etc.   Is there a way that I can use the python string formatting syntax to achieve this?   I know i can do it for individual column, but am looking to to this purely for the display within the notebook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a function to `float_format`, so can be anything

```
In [1]:

df = DataFrame(dict(A = [1.2345,10000.12345,1]))
df
Out[1]:
A
0    1.23450
1    10000.12345
2    1.00000
3 rows × 1 columns
In [4]:

pd.set_option('display.float_format',
      lambda x: '{:,.4f}'.format(x) if abs(x) < 10000 else '{:,.0f}'.format(x))
In [5]:

df
Out[5]:
A
0   1.2345
1   10,000
2   1.0000
3 rows × 1 columns
```