# Add thousands separator with comma at IPython.display HTML

Tags: python, dataframe, ipython

My goal is to create a dataframe using Python.display that contains formatted values such that every value has a comma separator for every thousands. Like for example, I am trying to format all the values in the dataframe from these:

[image] into these: [image]

I have been looking at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513615/add-decimal-mark-thousands-separators-to-a-number) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544891/pandas-dataframe-formatting), but I still can't make the formatting work. Does anyone have the solution to this?

Here's the code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML

styles = [
    hover(),
    dict(selector = "th",
         props = [("font-size", "110%"),
                  ("text-align", "left"),
                  ("background-color", "#cacaca")
                 ]
        )
    ]

column_01 = [2000000000, 21000000, 3000]
df = pd.DataFrame(column_01)
html = (df.style.set_table_styles(styles))

'{0:,}'.format(100000000)

html
```

Comment: you could convert numbers to strings `df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: '{0:,}'.format(x))`

Comment: you could convert numbers to floats `df[0] = df[0].astype(float)` and then you can set `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas uses a hard-coded format in pandas.formats.format.IntArrayFormatter to format the string. You will need to 'monkey patch' this with your own method. Have a look over here: [How to format IPython html display of Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876022/how-to-format-ipython-html-display-of-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you for the reference, and indeed it works. So based on the code from your given link, I add the `fmrt` variable into my code so it looks like this: `html = (df.style.set_table_styles(styles).format(frmt)`.