# Add Thousands Separator to a DataFrame that Has Empty Strings using Pandas Style

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipython

This is a follow-up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825963/add-thousands-separator-with-comma-at-ipython-display-html/40830498#40830498).

Using Pandas Style, I manage to format all of the values in a dataframe into values that have commas as thousands separators. However, when there are empty strings in a dataframe, the formatting fails.

Basically, my goal is convert from this: [image] to this: [image]

Can anyone help me with this?

This is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML

styles = [
    hover(),
    dict(selector = "th",
         props = [("font-size", "110%"),
                  ("text-align", "left"),
                  ("background-color", "#cacaca")
                 ]
        )
    ]

column_01 = ["", 2000000000, "", 21000000, 3000]
df = pd.DataFrame(column_01)

int_frmt = lambda x: "{:,}".format(x) # Integer
float_frmt = lambda x: "{:,.0f}".format(x) if x > 1e3 else "{:,.2f}".format(x) # Float
str_frmt = lambda x: "{:}".format(x) # <----- Added for empty strings but fails
frmt_map = {np.dtype("int64"): int_frmt,
            np.dtype("float64"): float_frmt,  
            np.dtype("S"): str_frmt # <----- Added for empty strings but fails
           }
frmt = {col: frmt_map[df.dtypes[col]] for col in df.columns if df.dtypes[col] in frmt_map.keys()}

html = (df.style.set_table_styles(styles).format(frmt))

html
```

Answer (score 2):

Using NumPy you could create a function to do the conversion, and `vectorize()` it. This can then be applied to your dataframe as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def thousands(x):
    try:
        return '{:,}'.format(int(x))
    except ValueError as e:
        return x

data = np.array(["","2000000000", "", "21000000", "3000"])
f_thousands = np.vectorize(thousands)
print f_thousands(data)
```

Giving you:

```
['' '2,000,000,000' '' '21,000,000' '3,000']
```

This attempts to convert the entry to an integer, and then use format's thousands separator. If the conversion fails, it returns the passed entry unchanged, e.g. blank

See also Python's [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=format%20mini#format-specification-mini-language) for more information.

---

Using Pandas, this could be done as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

def thousands(x):
    try:
        return '{:,}'.format(int(x))
    except ValueError as e:
        return x

data = pd.DataFrame(["","2000000000", "", "21000000", "3000"])
print data.applymap(thousands)
```

Giving you:

```
               0
0               
1  2,000,000,000
2               
3     21,000,000
4          3,000
```

Comment: Hi Martin. Does your code also work at `IPython.display Html`?